# How can I stop JDK from taking priority over JRE?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm running into the problem where I download the JRE 7 for Minecraft and the JDK 7 for programming and when I have both Installed Minecraft acts funny and does not work. The main problem is that in Minecraft, I can not select (highlight) any maps. Last time This happened it was because I had the 32-bit version of JRE installed, but that does not seem to be the problem this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the launcher, you can specify where your Java executable is located. Press `Edit Profile` and at the bottom, under "Java Settings (Advanced)", you have a setting called `Executable`. Check the box and put the path in. An example would be:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe